# Set value in Select (Input) of reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reactstrap

**Code:**

```
const [frequency, setFrequency] = useState({});

function handleSelect(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    setFrequency({
        ...frequency,
        [name]: value
    })
} 

<FormGroup>
    <Label for="exampleSelect">Select</Label>
    <Input type="select" name="select" id="exampleSelect" onChange= {handleSelect} >
    // I tried the below, But it does not seem to work
    <Input type="select" name="frequency" id="frequency" value={frequency.frequency}>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </Input>
  </FormGroup>
```

**Dropdown:**
[image: Dropdown]

**Selected value:**
[image: Selected value]

When I select the value it renders in the input but when I want to set the selected value.

Meaning, I want to set the value such that when I load it should **start** from a **selected value** not from `1`.

**So how can I set the value?**

I can `setState` by calling some select function. But in input tag I just want a value any value so when I refresh dropdown should show `xyx...1,2,3,4`.

Comment: If you want to preserve `state` across reloading of browser windows, you need some kind of persistent storage like *redis*, `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

Comment: I have value that I want to input...it's just an example where I want to set value in the input. Say I have selected value 3...it renders in Input...but let's say if I try as :

<Input type="select" name="select" id="exampleSelect" value="xyx">

On refresh Dropdown should render the value as xyz and then 1,2,3,4...so on.

I just want to give value to input so it can render that value. I hope my question is clear now

Comment: So doesn't the `Dropdown` select 1 as initial value? You want it to always have "xyz" selected on load?

Comment: Dropdown does select the value and renders it.....but I always want it to be "xyz" selected on load.

Comment: Then why not add it in as the first option?

Comment: I have edited the question as exactly how I want.....please let me know .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write `value="xyx"`, the value of `select` will always be `xyz` no matter what option you select.

So, instead of that you can provide `value` from react state and a `handleChange` function to change the value on select.

If you want to select the "first option" i.e. `xyz` at start, you can initialize the state with `xyz`:

```
export default function App() {
  const [frequency, setFrequency] = useState({ frequency: "xyz" });

  function handleSelect(e) {
    setFrequency((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }))
  }

  return (
    <>
      {JSON.stringify(frequency)}
      <FormGroup>
        <Label for="exampleSelect">Select</Label>
        <Input
          type="select"
          name="frequency"
          id="frequency"
          value={frequency.frequency}
          onChange={handleSelect}
        >
          <option>xyz</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
        </Input>
      </FormGroup>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-darkness-25ldn?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it is not working, I have edited my question. When I pass the value it doesn't seem to have any effect. It loads from the default value only, i.e. on load it renders xyz. I just want to render selected value on reload

Comment: It will render value only if i change input type to text instead of select

Comment: It is working just fine...there was typo in my passed variable name which was causing the issue. Thank you for your time. Cheere :).